# Pact http vs https endpoint testing

Tags: pact

Trying to write my first pact tests and I am not able to find answers to basic questions. Does consumer test and provider tests runs against mock servers only or should we be building our application locally (or on specific environment during CI/CD) and then run test against actual running application? Also, Is it possible for me to run consumer test against mock server and run provider tests against actual https endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This page answers all of those questions: https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/how_pact_works

> 1. Does consumer test and provider tests runs against mock servers only or should we be building our application locally (or on specific
>    environment during CI/CD) and then run test against actual running
>    application?

Consumer test: runs against a mock provider.

Provider test: pact simulates the consumer against a provider (see [3])

> 2. Is it possible for me to run consumer test against mock server

The consumer test must run against a Pact mock service, because that's how we record what you did and check that your requests match what's documented.

> 3. and run provider tests against actual https endpoint?

You can do this sort of "black box" approach, but better to run against a locally running provider that you can control.

Comment: To test provider against https endpoint. Do i need to set up any SSL? I am trying to run provider test against deployed service (which is basically https endpoint pointing to non-prod env)